# Android Bug after a long time

Tags: android, debugging

I have a bug that I am unable to reproduce on command or from the emulator, but seems to happen after leaving the app alone for a long time in the physical device.

All fragments continue to be responsive, but messages seem not to be passed from one fragment to another.

My best guess, is that some sort of garbage collecting might be breaking the links. Very vague question, but I'm desperate:

- What could lead to such a bug that happens "after a long time" (ie, hours)? What should I be looking for, in the code I write, if I suspect that the app isn't "restoring" successfully?
- Also, `adb logcat` when physical device is connected via usb debug should show up any error messages that I print with `log.e()`, correct?

---

**For future googlers and other novice coders** -- Today i learned, *Save references to fragments you create. Or, don't make fragments local variables.* I didn't need the reference to the fragment, only the contained view. As a result, the fragment got garbage collected and a new one recreated on restore, hence breaking the communication link.

Comment: Well that's a vague question indeed! Give us some more information regarding your app, please! Are there any background processes running, services, network communication, etc. Just give us some context!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like the activity (/fragment) is not save in the memory anymore - Android framework may destroy your activity any time it's in the background or backstack, and you should write your activities so they behave correctly when this happens. In order to beat this override `onSaveInstanceState` method.

You can cause it happen and try to reproduce it via developer options -> Don't keep activities

Comment: aaaa nice I'll give that a shot. Thanks!

Comment: yep -- that option is def reproducing it. Thanks!